# UrbanAirship using same RichPushUser after clear data/reinstall

Tags: android, urbanairship.com, richpush

I'm facing the problem that when i clear data of my app, or i just reinstall it, in the next run i get a new RichPushUser credential, and thus my inbox is completely empty as it looks as a new user.

What i am trying to accomplish is to allow the user use the same richpushuser in multiple devices, so they can access the same inbox.

I tried setting a fixed Alias, but that doesn't help. And the RichPushUser class only allow you to get id/password, but not setting them.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Alias is the way forward, what didn't work about it?

Comment: @weston i set the same alias every time (is hardcoded in fact), but every time i reinstall i get new richpushuser, new APID, new everything, and thus the inbox is empty. Is working for you just setting the alias?

Comment: And when you send to that alias? What happens?

Comment: And yes, works for us. We set the alias and send to that and it arrives.

Comment: @weston I have tried sending it directly to the APID as well as all devices option, and messages are delivered but after reinstall they are not in the inbox. But i don't see the option in the Message composer (in urban airship website) to send a push to an Alias. 

However, In the end we are going to send N messages to all devices, not 1 by 1 to each Alias. If one of those devices reinstall/clear data, or simply install the app (with same Alias) in his tablet, he should be able to access his Inbox.

Comment: maybe i am missing something, thanks for your help!